# SanDisk ImageMate SDDR-99 5-in-1 Card Reader help

Tags: 13.10, usb, card-reader

I am trying to use a SanDisk brand card-reader but the system does not respond when I plug in an SD card.  The SanDisk website lists only Windows as a compatible OS for this device, but I have seen ones like it listed in other posts under the lsusb command. This has led me to believe that it is possible to have one of these devices function properly in Ubuntu. Here are some command responses:

```
:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0781:9919 SanDisk Corp. Card Reader
```

This is with the sd card plugged in:

```
:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        58G   15G   41G  26% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            3.6G  4.0K  3.6G   1% /dev
tmpfs           728M  1.2M  727M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            3.6G  1.6M  3.6G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   64K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sdb1       913G   94M  867G   1% /drives/bigdrive


:~$ sudo lshw
*-scsi:3
          physical id: 7
          logical name: scsi6
          capabilities: emulated scsi-host
          configuration: driver=usb-storage
        *-disk UNCLAIMED
             description: SCSI Disk
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@6:0.0.0
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I should mention that SanDisk released a [firmware upgrade](http://kb.sandisk.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/108/~/updating-the-firmware-for-the-imagemate-sddr-89-%2812-in-1%29-%26-sddr-99-%285-in-1%29) that allows it to read sdhc cards which I also need help figuring out how to install.

***UPDATE***

Per chili 555's advice, here is what happens with the tail command:

```
whoopsie[1075]: online
kernel: [  204.926446] usb 1-5: reset high-speed USB     device number 2 using ehci-pci
kernel: [  215.165315] usb 1-5: reset high-speed USB   device number 2 using ehci-pci
whoopsie[1075]: online
whoopsie[1075]: online
kernel: [  231.398841] usb 1-5: reset high-speed USB    device number 2 using ehci-pci
kernel: [  231.650615] usb 1-5: reset high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
kernel: [  241.889494] usb 1-5: reset high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
kernel: [  242.026819] sd 6:0:0:0: Device offlined - not ready after error recovery
whoopsie[1075]: online
```

*I omitted two lines about the last message being repeated x number of times.

***UPDATE #2***

I have run the update and upgrade commands as suggested, but still receive to response from the system upon inserting the sd card. I thought I would try another tail command:

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog
Jan 21 23:37:08 matthew-MS-7721 kernel: [15628.768716] usb 8-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0781, idProduct=9919
Jan 21 23:37:08 matthew-MS-7721 kernel: [15628.768723] usb 8-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=4, SerialNumber=5
Jan 21 23:37:08 matthew-MS-7721 kernel: [15628.768727] usb 8-1: Product: ImageMate 5 in 1 Reader/Writer
Jan 21 23:37:08 matthew-MS-7721 kernel: [15628.768730] usb 8-1: Manufacturer: SanDisk 
Jan 21 23:37:08 matthew-MS-7721 kernel: [15628.768733] usb 8-1: SerialNumber: 0301243418
Jan 21 23:37:08 matthew-MS-7721 kernel: [15628.769853] usb-storage 8-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
Jan 21 23:37:08 matthew-MS-7721 kernel: [15628.769976] scsi7 : usb-storage 8-1:1.0
Jan 21 23:37:08 matthew-MS-7721 mtp-probe: checking bus 8, device 3: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.1/usb8/8-1"
Jan 21 23:37:08 matthew-MS-7721 mtp-probe: bus: 8, device: 3 was not an MTP device
Jan 21 23:37:09 matthew-MS-7721 kernel: [15629.769502] scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic  STORAGE DEVICE   9312 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0
Jan 21 23:37:09 matthew-MS-7721 kernel: [15629.769960] sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
```

All of that makes it seem like the system sees it, but cannot control it. Just my two cents.

Comment: Is there any clue when you open a terminal and do: tail -f /var/log/syslog and then insert the card? Get out of tail with Ctrl+c.

Comment: Question updated with response to tail command.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this is a well-known kernel bug that was fixed in the latest linux-image: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2164982 and: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=60717

What kernel version are you running?

```
uname -r
```

I suggest you update:

```
sudo apt-get-update && sudo apt-get -y upgrade
```

When I insert a USB cardreader in my system, the card mounts as follows:

> udisksd [1989] Mounted /dev/sdd1 at /media/chili/CANON_DC on behalf...

Do you have udisk and its dependencies installed? I checked in Synaptic and I have: libudisks2-0, udisks2, udisks, gnome-disk-utility and policykit-desktop-privileges installed. I suggest you check in Synaptic or, if Synaptic isn't installed, from the terminal:

```
sudo dpkg -s udisks
```

Continue for all the packages I listed and install any that are missing:

```
sudo apt-get install <package>
```

Then I suggest you reboot and try again with a 'tail' if it still isn't working.

Comment: I am running kernel version 3.11.0-15-generic. FYI I just did a recent fresh reinstall of 13.10. I also ran the update and upgrade commands. No luck with functionality so I tried the 'tail -f /var/log/syslog' command again and got some interesting responses which I will add to the question.

Comment: Please see my edit.